# Error "shasum check failed" when try to install firebase-tools

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-tools

I'm getting this error when try to install firebase-tools:

```
PS D:\Projects\Uni\firebase-functions-hello-world> npm install -g firebase-tools
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\
\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "firebase-tools"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\AdMin\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-8448-fdc26aac\registry.npmjs.org
\jju\-\jju-1.3.0.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: dadd9ef01924bc728b03f2f7979bdbd62f7a2aaa
npm ERR! Actual:   2a552ad636b1e23979c677ab9f360cf1ac578f89
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/jju/-/jju-1.3.0.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Projects\Uni\firebase-functions-hello-world\npm-debug.log
PS D:\Projects\Uni\firebase-functions-hello-world>
```

i also posted this issue on github which is https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/271

Comment: Did you try `npm cache clear`?

Comment: hey @Inzamam Malik did you find anything. were you able to solve this?

Comment: @sir george I even didn't figured why this error was coming, and I reinstalled windows to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Run the command again logged in as administrator.